# Google app engine and JPA

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa

I am try to persist an instance (entity) that contains a predefined instances(entities), with JPA and GAE, the relation is oneToOne, as the following:

```
@Entity class Address{ ... @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)private City city;}

@Entity class City{...}
```

I created city instance(entity) and persist it, works good, when trying to create Address instance that contains the created city instance(since from UI, it selected from dropdown box), I got the following exception:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Detected attempt to establish Address(no-id-yet) as the parent of City(20) but the entity identified by City(20) has already been persisted without a parent.  A parent cannot be established or changed once an object has been persisted.
```

Is there any annotation(s) should be used in order to make this happen?

Thanks in advance

Comment: so you use GAE "owned" relations and have problems with ownership. Quoting your persistence code (what object is passed to persist, where are your transactions?) would be a start, because without it you aren't defining to people what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how DataStore stores keys. Your type of relation is Parent/Child, so for City you will have Adress as a Parent. This mean that you will have composite key with parent as an Address. Your City was already persists so you will not be able to change key (keys can not be changes dynamically after creation. They are immutable).

I do not think that OneToOne reference is suitable for you. Why do you need a separate object? If you really need it - do not try to keep reference integrity. It is very expensive in NoSQL and could cause a lot of problems.